# load only visible elements in listview android

Tags: android, listview, drawable

I'd like to know if my view is visible in my listview
is there an listner in my adapter to know if the curent view is visible ?

I don't want to load too much drawables in my listview

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what the list adapter does for you. `getView()` gets only called for visible Views. When a view is not visible anymore, it gets recycled and passed to `getView()` as the parameter `convertView`. For your drawables, you should consider to use an LRU cache.